# Как вставить код от kotlin в java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Возникла проблема. В документации для разработчика написан код на kotlin, а у меня приложение на java. В ответ они мне ответили, что возможно вставить в java код, код от kotlin. Как это возможно сделать в Android Studio. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А разве нельзя kotlin импортировать в java просто командой `import <имя файла на kotlin>.*;`

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html#adding-kotlin-source-code-to-an-existing-java-project

Comment: А можно поподробнее, с фрагментом кода.

Comment: А можно поподробнее что конкретно вы хотите? Вставить кусок котлин-кода в java-класс? Нет, нельзя. Добавить в проект исходники на котлине? Нет проблем - включайте поддержку котлина через меню `tools` и вперёд. Использовать котлин-класс в java-классе? Точно так же как и обычный java-класс импортируйте и используйте - никакой разницы нет.